# Python " Traceback (most recent call last) "

Tags: python

Помогите пожалуйста, как решить проблему?
Код:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

HOST = 'https://mmo13.ru/'
URL = 'https://mmo13.ru/games/'
HEADERS = {
    'accept': '*/*',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.102 Safari/537.36'
}

def get_html(url, params =''):
    r = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS, params=params)
    return r


def get_content(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')      
    items = soup.find_all('div', class_='games-view')
    games = []

    for item in items:
        games.append(
            {
                'title':item.find('div', class_='title atxt').get_text(),
                'link_game': item.find('div', class_='title atxt').find('a').get('href')
            }     
        )
    return games

html = get_html(URL)
print(get_content(html.text))
```

И ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Users\Wottsan\Desktop\Проект\Parser.py", line 32, in <module>
    print(get_content(html.text))
  File "E:\Users\Wottsan\Desktop\Проект\Parser.py", line 25, in get_content
    'title':item.find('div', class_='title_atxt').get_text(),
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'
```

Comment: Не находится такой элемент на странице - item.find('div', class_='title atxt')

Comment: Спасибо, вроде понял

Answer (score 1):

```
def get_content(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')      
    items = soup.find_all('div', class_='games-view')
    games = []

    for item in items:

       if item.find('div', class_='title atxt') == None:
           continue
       games.append(
        {
            'title': item.find('div', class_='title atxt').get_text(),
            'link_game': item.find('div', class_='title atxt').find('a').get('href')
        }
    )
    return games
```

Comment: Этот код так же упадёт, т.к. ошибка не из-за того, что find('div'...) равен None, а потому что find('a') равен None. При этом title всё ещё определяется. Так что простым continue здесь не обойтись.

Comment: Проверено не упадет.Тег 'а' не во всех items есть так-же как тег 'div' с классом 'title atxt'.  Можно было сделать и через  try  except.